# Opening and hiding web-page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I tried using window.open() with '_blank' and then window.blur() in chrome, but the web-page does not hide itself from the user. All I want to do is open a child web-page from its parent (with same origin) while hiding the child, scrape some of the html from the child's body, then close the child web-page. I know I could also do this with an iframe, but I am building a chrome extension that needs to interact with the child web-page and won't do so with an iframe, unless there's a way I can do that? Here is my working code I have so far:

```
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  var num = links.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var win = window.open(links[i].href, "_blank");
    win.blur();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  var num = links.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    var win = window.open(links[i].href,"_blank")

    win.close();

  }
```

with modifying your method window will be closed immediately but the user will able to detect that(means any window is opened and close sudden) (tested on chrome)

```
      var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
      var num = links.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        var win = window.open(links[i].href,"_blank",'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none', '')

        win.close();     

  }
```

with this method, the user will not able to see if there is any window open or not.

Comment: Yeah so that opened up the webpages to far right corner of my computer screen, so it's still not really invisible. I tried using iframes instead and was able to hide them, but having issues with accessing element's inside multiple iframes when looping over them.

Comment: if you want to really make it invisible you have to use electron js . then you can do that. let me know if you require any help from me.

Comment: What's electron js?